# pypy2.7.1.1 fails using pyenv

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install python version pypy2.7.1.1 using the following

```
pyenv install pypy2.7-7.1.1
```

I get the following error:

```
Downloading pypy2.7-v7.1.1-osx64.tar.bz2...
-> https://downloads.python.org/pypy/pypy2.7-v7.1.1-osx64.tar.bz2
Installing pypy2.7-v7.1.1-osx64...
Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py...
error: failed to install pip via get-pip.py

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.2.3 using 0000000000)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/zt/q3p12vyx3l990yc32wmybqdr0000gs/T/python-build.20210428193745.1720
Results logged to /var/folders/zt/q3p12vyx3l990yc32wmybqdr0000gs/T/python-build.20210428193745.1720.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/zt/q3p12vyx3l990yc32wmybqdr0000gs/T/python-build.20210428193745.1720 ~
/var/folders/zt/q3p12vyx3l990yc32wmybqdr0000gs/T/python-build.20210428193745.1720/pypy2.7-v7.1.1-osx64 /var/folders/zt/q3p12vyx3l990yc32wmybqdr0000gs/T/python-build.20210428193745.1720 ~
ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.
```

since pip was moved for 2.7 how do I install this now? is there a different way to install deprecated versions of python now?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue on Mac OS 10.15.7 (Catalina).

This is how I was finally able to install Python 2.7 via pyenv

```
export GET_PIP_URL=https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
PYTHON_BUILD_HOMEBREW_OPENSSL_FORMULA=openssl@1.0 pyenv install 2.7.5
```

I realize that you are trying to install pypy and not Python, but hopefully the method above helps you, or others!